# HDD Issues: SMART, Self Test & Extended test point to Ultra DMA Connector / SATA cable connection issues - Accurate Diagnoisis & Solution?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, cable, smart, connector

- I know the default line being please back up your data - done that and will attemp doing again if this "connection" allows it. That would be stating the obvious to someone who has played with partitions/ partition tables, bad blocks, and deep HDD tools.
- Please do not respond with amatuer responses when I've posted very specific technical details and will update with more information from various deep tech HDD tool & utilities
- I'd prefer to hear from people who understand this deeper and can focus on the tech details being presented; and ideally having experienced the same (connector/ cable comm issue maybe fixed by reseating cable or changing it) and/ or solving it some way.

**CHKDSK Output:**

CHKDSK was run before diagnosis with the following HDD Tools.

```
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume dismounted.  All opened handles to this volume are now invalid.
Volume label is W81_SP_CP2_GPT.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 1089332.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 1089363.
  1184768 file records processed.
File verification completed.
  6772 large file records processed.
  0 bad file records processed.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 3617.
CHKDSK discovered free space marked as allocated in the bitmap for index $I30 for file 3617.
Sorting index $I30 in file 3617.
Deleting index entry f_001cd5 in index $I30 of file 3617.
Deleting index entry f_00358b in index $I30 of file 3617.
Deleting index entry f_00358c in index $I30 of file 3617.
Deleting index entry f_00358f in index $I30 of file 3617.
Deleting index entry f_003593 in index $I30 of file 3617.
Deleting index entry f_003594 in index $I30 of file 3617.
Deleting index entry f_003595 in index $I30 of file 3617.
Deleting index entry f_00379b in index $I30 of file 3617.
Deleting index entry f_00379c in index $I30 of file 3617.
Deleting index entry f_00379d in index $I30 of file 3617.
Deleting index entry f_00379e in index $I30 of file 3617.
Deleting index entry f_0037b3 in index $I30 of file 3617.
Deleting index entry f_0037c7 in index $I30 of file 3617.
Deleting index entry f_0037db in index $I30 of file 3617.
Deleting index entry 000004.log in index $I30 of file 6759.
Deleting index entry LOG in index $I30 of file 359474.
Deleting index entry LOG.old in index $I30 of file 359474.
  1399772 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
CHKDSK is scanning unindexed files for reconnect to their original directory.
Recovering orphaned file LOG.old (4637) into directory file 359474.
Recovering orphaned file f_0037ad (21599) into directory file 3617.
Recovering orphaned file f_00361b (26764) into directory file 3617.
Recovering orphaned file LOG (33890) into directory file 359474.
Recovering orphaned file f_0035bf (44070) into directory file 3617.
Recovering orphaned file f_0035d3 (214922) into directory file 3617.
Recovering orphaned file f_0037a4 (604470) into directory file 3617.
Recovering orphaned file f_0035f8 (604522) into directory file 3617.
Recovering orphaned file f_0035ef (604527) into directory file 3617.
Recovering orphaned file f_0035fb (819870) into directory file 3617.
Skipping further messages about recovering orphans.
  59 unindexed files scanned.
  58 unindexed files recovered to original directory.
CHKDSK is recovering remaining unindexed files.
  1 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.
    Lost and found is located at \found.001


Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.
Inserting data attribute into file 1089332.
Inserting data attribute into file 1089363.
  107505 data files processed.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
Usn Journal verification completed.
Correcting errors in the master file table's (MFT) BITMAP attribute.
Correcting errors in the Volume Bitmap.

Windows has made corrections to the file system.
No further action is required.

 396296191 KB total disk space.
 290621640 KB in 988287 files.
    494764 KB in 107505 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
   1262567 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 103917220 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
  99074047 total allocation units on disk.
  25979305 allocation units available on disk.
```

**HD Tune Pro 5.60**

```
HD Tune Pro: ST500DM002-1BD142 Health

ID                               Current  Worst    ThresholdData             Status     
(01) Raw Read Error Rate         111      99       6        30537504         ok         
(03) Spin Up Time                100      98       0        0                ok         
(04) Start/Stop Count            99       99       20       1429             ok         
(05) Reallocated Sector Count    100      100      36       0                ok         
(07) Seek Error Rate             87       60       30       500295343        ok         
(09) Power On Hours Count        84       84       0        14547            ok         
(0A) Spin Retry Count            100      100      97       0                ok         
(0C) Power Cycle Count           99       99       20       1463             ok         
(B7) SATA Downshift Count        100      100      0        0                ok         
(B8) End To End Error Detection  100      100      99       0                ok         
(BB) Uncorrectable Error Count   100      100      0        0                ok         
(BC) Command Timeout             100      1        0        4295035605       ok         
(BD) Unknown Attribute           100      100      0        0                ok         
(BE) Airflow Temperature         58       51       45       5068619818       ok         
(C2) Temperature                 42       49       0        140737488355370  ok         
(C3) Hardware ECC Recovered      46       37       0        30537504         ok         
(C5) Current Pending Sector      100      100      0        0                ok         
(C6) Offline Uncorrectable       100      100      0        0                ok         
**(C7) Interface CRC Error Count   200      119      0        10843            attention**  
(F0) Head Flying Hours           100      253      0        24558623010203   ok         
(F1) Unknown Attribute           100      253      0        -1133036663      ok         
(F2) Unknown Attribute           100      253      0        345706263        ok         

Health Status         : ok


HD Tune Pro: ST500DM002-1BD142 Health

ID                               Current  Worst    ThresholdData             Status     
(01) Raw Read Error Rate         117      99       6        161640440        ok         
(03) Spin Up Time                100      98       0        0                ok         
(04) Start/Stop Count            99       99       20       1435             ok         
(05) Reallocated Sector Count    100      100      36       0                ok         
(07) Seek Error Rate             87       60       30       505023506        ok         
(09) Power On Hours Count        84       84       0        14720            ok         
(0A) Spin Retry Count            100      100      97       0                ok         
(0C) Power Cycle Count           99       99       20       1468             ok         
(B7) SATA Downshift Count        100      100      0        0                ok         
(B8) End To End Error Detection  100      100      99       0                ok         
(BB) Uncorrectable Error Count   100      100      0        0                ok         
(BC) Command Timeout             100      1        0        4295042332       ok         
(BD) Unknown Attribute           100      100      0        0                ok         
(BE) Airflow Temperature         57       51       45       5086249003       ok         
(C2) Temperature                 43       49       0        140737488355371  ok         
(C3) Hardware ECC Recovered      50       37       0        161640440        ok         
(C5) Current Pending Sector      100      100      0        0                ok         
(C6) Offline Uncorrectable       100      100      0        0                ok         
(C7) Interface CRC Error Count   200      1        0        26952            attention  
(F0) Head Flying Hours           100      253      0        59541131636295   ok         
(F1) Unknown Attribute           100      253      0        1173736671       ok         
(F2) Unknown Attribute           100      253      0        1420407677       ok         

Health Status         : ok
```

**Hard Disk Sentinel Pro 5.01**

```
**Extended Self Test** 

Problems occurred between the *communication of the disk and the host* **10843 times.**
In case of sudden system crash, reboot, blue-screen-of-death, inaccessible file(s)/folder(s), it is recommended to verify data and power cables, connections - and if possible try different cables to prevent further problems.
More information: http://www.hdsentinel.com/hard_disk_case_communication_error.php

No actions needed.  


**Extended Self Test** 

Problems occurred between the *communication of the disk and the host* **26952 times.**
In case of sudden system crash, reboot, blue-screen-of-death, inaccessible file(s)/folder(s), it is recommended to verify data and power cables, connections - and if possible try different cables to prevent further problems.
More information: http://www.hdsentinel.com/hard_disk_case_communication_error.php

No actions needed.
```

http://www.hdsentinel.com/hard_disk_case_communication_error.php - Reveals:

> **Hard disk case: communication errors**
> Problems occurred between the communication of the hard disk and the host
> This example shows the status of a Samsung SATA hard disk.

**Hard disk problems reported**

- the hard disk was used in a different computer system without hard disk monitoring
- no significant problems reported: the hard disk is working as expected

**First hard disk checks**
Initially, the hard disk health reported is 100 %. The text description shows no problems with the hard disk but shows communications problems:

*Problems occurred between the communication of the disk and the host 122 times.*

**Hard disk cable and connection issues**

According the text description, numerous data transfer (communication) problems found. In most cases this is not really related to the hard disk, but related to the connections and/or data cables. For example loose SATA cable connections frequently cause this issue.

It is recommended to verify both the power and the data cable connected to the hard drive. If you see the plugs do not fit properly, you should change the data cable to a different one, for example a SATA cable with a metal clip to fix the connection:

**SATA hard disk cable with metal latch - Image**

The error counter counts all errors found during the lifetime of the hard disk. It means that **the errors do not reset automatically** after fixing or replacing the cables. So if things will be improved, the error-counter will not increase further (the current amount of errors remain reported).

If the problems are corrected, it is possible to manually **reset the error counter** in Hard Disk Sentinel:

- open the **S.M.A.R.T. page** of the hard disk drive
- locate the **#199 Ultra ATA CRC error count** attribute
- locate the **Offset column** for this attribute and click on the 0 between - and + and enter the error count value reported in the text description but with negative sign.

This will reset the error-counter to zero. So the error text will be removed from the text description and it will be displayed again only if there will be new such problems found.

(Skipped Example on Reset error count)  Continued..

> **Recommendations**

- Check data and power cables and connections of the hard disks and SSDs
- Consider using high quality cables, for example SATA cables with SATA 6G designation (especially if you prefer to use a SATA 6G device)
- Avoid using power cable extenders, splitters
- IDE/ATA hard disks: make sure to connect the hard disk cable properly. Use 80-wire standard cable (not round one) and the "longer" end should be connected to the motherboard, the shorter end to the master device and the center connector should be to the slave device. If there is an optical drive on the same cable, the hard disk should be always set to master and the optical drive should be the slave device.
- Disk menu -> Surface Test functions can cause high amount of traffic transferred between the hard disk and the controller (host). This way they can be effectively used to check if there are further data communication errors. Disk menu -> Surface Test -> Refresh data area is one of the best methods to test as it automatically performs verification by comparing the content of the sectors after the "refresh" with the original content.
- Other system factors (for example generic overheat, not stable power source, overclocking) can also cause data communication issues. It is recommended to verify and eliminate these issues also if possible.

**UPDATE: Changed & Reseated SATA Cables/ Ports >>  July 8 / 9 - Overnight  - Surface Test**

```
**Surface Test - Report**

Read test

Block
  Good: 10000
  Damaged: 0
  Bad: 0

Hard disk test details
  0 new reallocated sectors found
  0 new spin retry errors found
  0 new pending sectors found
  0 new off-line uncorrectable sectors found

**OK**
```

**Ran a 3rd Round of the former "Extended Self Test" to see if the error numbers above change again or it was just due to poor SATA connection issues.**

- Backed up important stuff off the Disk
- A third round of Extended Self Test does not show any change in the SATA CRC numbers after re-seating so I am guessing that was resolved.
- I will log & watch certain parameters and numbers over next 1-2 weeks to see if anything gets worse or remains constant; thereby pointing towards the SATA connector issues being the prime cause.

Comment: So... what is the question? You presented lots of information - but you didn't ask any question... My goto software for doing HDD testing is SpinRite (and the only affiliation I have is that I own a copy of the software, and it has been allowing me to make the HDD usable again to the point that I can copy all data out). Another one that I will use for data recovery is TestDisk.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @DavidPostill - What is diagnosis & solution?

Comment: @Darius - What is the diagnosis & possible fixes as per the data presented from various tools?

Answer (score 2):

There is the communication problem between HDD and computer..

Laptop or tower?

If tower, try to use a different sata port, even disconnect you DVD rom drive and plug HDD instead. The damage could be connector wise.

Laptop, I would suggest to use a SATA to USB adaptator.

It could be the HDD board that is problematic, it would require to put the data disk in a new HDD of the same type and no dust must enter while it's done.. If you want to get the data no matter what.

https://www.ontrack.com

Comment: Its a PC Tower not laptop

Answer (score 1):

Diagnosis: You have two different problems: (1) SATA transport is bad, and (2) your harddisk is showing considerable wear.

You seem to have solved (1) by re-seating the SATA cables. Note that the surface test doesn't tell you anything about SATA transport, what you need to watch is the `Interface CRC Error Count` SMART attribute.

For (2), remember that SMART values are normalized to 100, and lower is worse. You have a significant seek error rate (which means problems with the head mechanics), your hardware error recovery correction rate is also significant, and the disk seems to get too hot. So the harddisk is showing signs of ageing, and while it's not failing yet, I wouldn't trust it with important data. The reallocated sector count is zero, so nothing really bad has happened up to now, which is good. Keep watching this number; if it starts to go up, the disk will fail soon, and probably disastrously.

Try to improve cooling for the disk if possible. If this is a desktop, in your place I'd use this disk for system files from now on, and get a new disk for your data. Daily backups are a must now if you keep using it.

**Edit**

To repeat, parameters to watch are `(07) Seek Error Rate` and `(C3) Hardware ECC Recovered` (which are already in the "yellow" range), then `(01) Raw Read Error Rate` and `(BB) Uncorrectable Error Count` and `(05) Reallocated Sector Count` (which are still fine, but will indicate more severe problems if they start to go down). For the first, see if improved cooling helps. And of course, any other parameter that goes significantly below 100 is also worth watching.

To describe the current situation more abstractly: With modern high-density disks, errors on the lower levels are expected, and the harddisk has mechanisms to correct them. But your harddisk is already working much harder at correcting them than it should (which is a sign of wear), though the margin is still big enough nothing really bad happens.

Comment: I'll try to figure out, which parameters (if you can clarify, better) you mentioned stay or get worse and log them and report back in 1-2 weeks